# Upload backup of PostgreSQL DB

Tags: sql, postgresql

During upload of back-up database I run the command:

```
pg_restore 20150401.backup > backup.txt
```

This gives me the following warrning:

> pg_restore: [archiver] WARNING: don't know how to set owner for object
>   MATERIALIZED VIEW

And indeed when backup is up the materilzed view doesn't exists.
So  I need to run it's creation code in a query manualy. This is very inconvenient.

I'm runing PostgreSQL 9.3.3

Is there a way to fix this problem? Was this issue addressed in future releases?

Comment: There is a bug fix in 9.3.5 relating to pg_dump and materialized views. The current 9.3. patch version is 9.3.16 - you should really upgrade. Maybe that problem goes away then.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43363051/how-to-upgrate-minor-release-in-postgresql?noredirect=1#comment73789137_43363051  i'm trying to find how to perform updates but there aren't guides on how to do it..

Comment: Not sure what else you need apart from "replace the executable". Use whatever installer/package manager you use in your operating system to install the new binaries. There is no magic about that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Is it possible to create them "on the side" and simply replace the folder? in that way if there is a problem i can return the old files.

Comment: Again: this depends on your operating system and how you installed the current version. You can always backup those folders before you upgrade (but you should have a regular backup of your server anyway, so just rely on that)

Answer (score 0):

you can get the definition querying it, eg:

**create view:**

```
t=# create materialized view so55 as select * from pg_tables where tablename like 'gt%';
SELECT 0
```

**get ddl:**

```
t=# \pset format unaligned
Output format is unaligned.
t=# select concat('create view ',schemaname,'.',matviewname,' as ',definition) from pg_matviews where matviewname = 'so55';
concat
create view public.so55 as  SELECT pg_tables.schemaname,
    pg_tables.tablename,
    pg_tables.tableowner,
    pg_tables.tablespace,
    pg_tables.hasindexes,
    pg_tables.hasrules,
    pg_tables.hastriggers
   FROM pg_tables
  WHERE (pg_tables.tablename ~~ 'gt%'::text);
(1 row)
```

Comment: I have the defintion saved I can run it manualy, I simply asked if there is a solution to the fact the it doesn't happen automaticly. I'm trying to avoid the manual query

Comment: ah - sorry. mistook "fix the problem" with "any solution"