# How to upgrate minor release in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3.3 and I wish to update it.
Since I never done it before I consider to take the safe side and first upgrade to 9.3.4

According to this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/upgrading.html 
What I should do is:

> To update between compatible versions, you simply replace the
>   executables while the server is down and restart the server.

What are the exact steps to do it (as safe as possible)?
I've seen a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249371/minor-upgrade-of-postgres-9-3-9-to-9-3-12-on-ubuntu-14-04 that was not answered as well.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu/Debian and you just want to update between minor versions of PG then simple "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade" works OK for us - we do it even on production site. But of course check what is "upgrade" telling you in list of packages intended for update! And of course update restarts postgresql service! Otherwise minor versions do not bring any changes in data files format so it is completely safe regarding database.